# Passing parameter value (sometimes get null value) into stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

i want to pass parameter value sometimes get null value into stored procedure,my stored procuder look like this

```
USE [Stock]
GO
ALTER Proc [dbo].[Add_ItemQte]
@ID_Item int,
@ID_Supplier int,
@Qantity_ItemQte int,
@Date_ItemQte date,
@Lenght_ItemQte int,
@Widht_ItemQte int,
@WightT_ItemQte float,
@ID_Location int,
@ID_Project int=null
AS
INSERT INTO ItemQuantity
       ([ID_Item]
       ,[ID_Supplier]
       ,[Qantity_ItemQte]
       ,[Date_ItemQte]
       ,[Lenght_ItemQte]
       ,[Widht_ItemQte]
       ,[WightT_ItemQte]
       ,[ID_Location]
       ,[ID_Project])
 VALUES
       (@ID_Item
       ,@ID_Supplier
       ,@Qantity_ItemQte
       ,@Date_ItemQte
       ,@Lenght_ItemQte
       ,@Widht_ItemQte
       ,@WightT_ItemQte
       ,@ID_Location
       ,@ID_Project)
```

my c# code look like this

```
        public void Add_ItemQte(int Name, int Supplier, int Qantity, DateTime Date, int Lenght,int Widht,double WightT,int Location, Nullable<int> Project)
    {
        DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
        DAL.Open();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[9];

        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ID_Item", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[0].Value = Name;

        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@ID_Supplier", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[1].Value = Supplier;

        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@Qantity_ItemQte", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[2].Value = Qantity;

        param[3] = new SqlParameter("@Date_ItemQte", SqlDbType.Date);
        param[3].Value = Date;

        param[4] = new SqlParameter("@Lenght_ItemQte", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[4].Value = Lenght;

        param[5] = new SqlParameter("@Widht_ItemQte", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[5].Value = Widht;

        param[6] = new SqlParameter("@WightT_ItemQte", SqlDbType.Float);
        param[6].Value = WightT;

        param[7] = new SqlParameter("@ID_Location", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[7].Value = Location;

        param[8] = new SqlParameter("@ID_Project", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[8].Value = Project;

        DAL.ExcuteCommande("Add_ItemQte", param);
        DAL.Close();

    }
```

and i use this code to save my data

```
            for (int i=0;i<gridView1.RowCount;i++)
        {
            prd.Add_ItemQte(Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "IDNom")), Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "IDFournisseur")),
            Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Quantité")), Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Date")),
            Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Longueur")), Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Largeur")),
            Convert.ToDouble(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Poids Total")), Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "IDLocalisation")),
            Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "IDProjet")));

        }
```

when IDProjet column have a value the code run without error but when it does not contain any value i get this error:Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.I do not want to save 0 if the value is null because i will do some filtering depending on that column, how i can solve this problem,thanks in advance i am very sorry for the previous code .

Comment: On which like do you get that error? You are not reading from the DB so that error message seems weird.

Comment: check type before processing it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the loop that reads the value for each project from your grid

```
for (int i=0;i<gridView1.RowCount;i++)
{
    object value = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "IDProjet");
    int? prjID = null;
if(value != null && Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int temp))
    prjID = temp;

    prd.Add_ItemQte(...., prjID);
}
```

Next change the creation of your parameters to a more explici

```
param[8] = new SqlParameter("@ID_Project", SqlDbType.Int);
param[8].Value = Project.HasValue ? Project : (object)DbNull.Value;
```

Comment: thank you very much and I am so sorry for all the trouble

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert `DBNull` to `int` so you should use some expression like below as the second parameter:

```
txtDescription.Text == DBNull.Value ? txtDescription.Text : Convert.ToInt32(txtDescription.Text)
```

Comment: Did you try your proposed solution? It cannot be compiled. By the way a TextBox.Text is never null or DbNull.

Comment: @Steve yes but did not work for me ,In fact the code is bigger than this and I tried to shorten it but it seems that I made another mistake, I will write the question again

Comment: I think you have an invalid format exception if your textbox is empty

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
param[1].Value = DBNull.Value.Equals(description)? 0 : description;
```

You can't assign a null value to an integer datatype;

or another option change int to varchar:

```
Create Proc Add_Grade
@Name varchar (10),
@Description varchar (10)
```

Comment: Where do you get your first line? Is that a proposed solution to the question? A nullable int is not equal to DbNull.Value.

Comment: thanks @steve just showing him a null data from DB. I know it can't be done to an `int DataType` if we use `description=null` in code behind. I'm just curious about this error `DBNull to other types`;

Answer (score 0):

if txtDescription is null then you can make it a "0". which will convert to 0

```
prd.Add_Grade(txtName.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtDescription?.Text ?? "0"));
```

Comment: Again, a TextBox.Text is never null. Just try to assign a null value to the property and try to reread it immediately, you will get an empty string not a null.

Comment: In the question, the author originally stated, before editing it, that the value was null. The coalesce operator fixes that, but if it is not null but empty as you state it will throw, I think that I missed that it was a textbox.  Good catch. +1